# Persist collection using 2 tables and Entities, Java/Spring

Tags: java, spring, entities

I am building a Spring boot microservice and I am building the data access layer using entities. I would like to map 1 entity, `Transactions`, to 2 tables. The first table "transactions" will have a transaction_id. The second table will also use the same transaction_id as its primary key, as well as other attributes.  What is easiest way to do this?
In other words:

```
@Entity
class Transactions {

    @Id
    private Long transactionId;

    ??@OneToMany?? ( <--what do I put here?)
    private List<Groceryitem> items;
}
```

The first table will store a Long transaction ID and a List of `GroceryItem`'s like so:

```
Table: transactions
 ______________________
|                      |
| transactionId: Long  |
|                      |
| List<GroceryItem>    |
|______________________|
```

essentially making the first table look like this:

```
 transcation_id     |  
 --------------------
 1          
 2
```

Grocery Item is a class that contains a field `Float price` like so:

```
class GroceryItem {
    private String itemName;
    private Float price;

    Float getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    String getName() {
        return this.itemName;
    }
}
```

I want to store the List of Grocery Items in a second table, and use the same `transactionId` as the primary key for the second table. I would also like to be able to expand Grocery Item to include more attributes in the future.

```
Table: items
 ______________________
|                      |
| transactionId: Float |
|                      |
| List<GroceryItem>    |
|                      |
| name:    String      |
|______________________|
```

The second table would look like this:

```
 transaction_id     |    name    |    price    
 ------------------------------------------
 1                     carrot        15.00
 1                     apple         13.99
 2                     apple         3.00
```

How do I properly annotate the Transaction and Grocery Item classes?

Comment: I am new to using entities and hibernate. I have been researching for the last 2 days and it is sometime difficult to translate my OO thinking to an entity based one when asking the question. I have made edits to help clarify my question. @TheHeadRush

Comment: No matter how you slice it, "How do I properly annotate the Transaction and Grocery Item classes?" is an overly broad question that demonstrates little personal effort. I'd suggest that you proceed and when you have a specific question about why an annotation is working differently than you expect, ask about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good solution in your case is to use unidirectional relation One to Many, where you have list of GroceryItem in the Transaction class. You can do it in this way as below:

```
@Entity
public Transaction {
...
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id")
private List<GroceryItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class GroceryItem {
...
}
```

In case if you have relation one to one e.g. Transaction + Transaction Details. You can think about @SecondaryTable, where part of Entity can be stored in one table (TRANSACTION) the second part can be stored in second table (TRANSACTION_DETAILS)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow; can you add some context/information on what this code does? We strive to make answers holistically useful rather than just a tempting copy-paste opportunity (which can result in dangerous situations for those who don't really know what this code might do).